# Check if the embeddings preserve the true space structure

Tags: neural-networks, similarities, embeddings

I obtained the embeddings from the pre-classification layer of a neural network for 600K instances. Each embedding's dimension is 1024, thus we have a sample of the embedding space, $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^{1024}$ with a size of 600k. I have the "true" space of this sample in which the true space lies in 4 dim space, $\mathcal{Y} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$. I want to test whether the embeddings preserve the local and global structure of the true space. What I had in mind is to construct two similarity matrices for both the real space and embedding space and then find the nearest K points for each row (i.e., instance/node). Let us call the set of nearest K points for the embedding-based similarity matrix and the real-space-based similarity matrix $S^1_i \text{ and } S^2_i$ respectively, where  $i$ is the ith row. Then take the dice coefficient for each row $i$$: \text{score}_i = \frac{|S^1_i \cap S^2_i|}{|S^1_i| + |S^2_i|}$. However, this wouldn't be feasible as the similarity matrix do not fit in memory. Any other suggestions?